Routing query to different Postgres DB instances
I have a requirement to route the incoming query to respective DB instances. I'm new to managing Databases.
eg: I have 4 Postgres RDS. say rds_master, rds1, rds2 and rds3
rds_master contains schema table which has mapping of which subdomain points to which schema

rds1 contains schema 1 to 10    (host - rds1.abc.com)
rds2 contains schema 11 to 20   (host - rds2.abc.com)
rds3 contains schema 21 to 30   (host - rds3.abc.com)

I'm planning to have a middleman from application server to rds (some db proxy).
So when the request comes from application server (host - rds.abc.com), db proxy should identify the schema information and send the request to respective rds instance.
eg: 10.abc.com running some query, then proxy should route the incoming query to rds2.abc.com
How can I achieve this routing algorithm? is there any db proxy that can do this?
Help is much needed for this. Thanks in advance.

Before inventing your own sharding solution, have a look at Citus and PL/Proxy.

Do you control the schemas of all those 40 databases? They could have the same or different schemas...

All schemas are same. Its just each schema represents 1 customer for us.
